# Handle fetch api errors in useEffect and set error

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

I have `useEffect` in one of my components that fetches data from an api.

I wanna handle two types of errors -

1. Api is unavailable (say server is down)
2. Request made is invalid (request made to incorrect endpoint)

And, call `setError` when any of these errors happens.

This is how I solved it -

```js
const [error, setError] = useState(null)

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchModels = async () => {
        let res
        try {
            res = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/models/')
        }
        catch (e) {
            if (e instanceof (TypeError)) {
                setError('Could not fetch data. Please try again')
                return
            }
        }

        if (!res.ok) {
            setError('Could not fetch data. Please try again')
            return
        }

        const data = await res.json()
        setModels(data)
        setError(null)
    }
    fetchModels()
}, [])
```

Even though this works, I really believe there must be a better way to do what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: What exactly bothers you? (Besides the last `setErrors(null)` which is not needed because it's already`null`)

Comment: Best would be to have an API service inside your app structure that handles everything this in background

Comment: since you asked for a better way,  you can use [react-query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/) or other async data synchronization library, this will reduce lots of boiler plate and also is very easy to integrate inside an existing codebase

Comment: @MoshFeu I am fetching data this way in other places also and also I feel I am missing handling some edge cases in my code since I am new to Fetch API